# How do i filter bad or corrupted rows from a spark data frame after casting

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

df1

```
+-------+-------+-----+
|   ID  |  Score| hits|
+-------+-------+-----+
|     01|    100| Null|
|     02|   Null|   80|
|     03|  spark|    1|
|     04|    300|    1|
+-------+-------+-----+
```

after casting Score to int and hits to float I get the below dataframe:

df2

```
+-------+-------+-----+
|   ID  |  Score| hits|
+-------+-------+-----+
|     01|    100| Null|
|     02|   Null| 80.0|
|     03|   Null|  1.0|
|     04|    300|  1.0|
+-------+-------+-----+
```

Now I want to extract only the bad records , bad records mean that null produced after casting.

I want to do the operations only on existing dataframe. Please help me out if there is any build-in way to get the bad records after casting.

Please also consider this is sample dataframe. The solution should solve for any number of columns and any scenario.

I tried by separating the null records from both dataframes and compare them. Also i have thought of adding another column with number of nulls and then compare the both dataframes if number of nulls is grater in df2 than in df1 then those are bad one. But i think these solutions are pretty old school.

I would like to know the better way to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom function/udf to convert string to integer and map non integer values to specific number eg. -999999999.

Later you can filter on -999999999 to identify originally non integer records.

```
def udfInt(value):
    if value is None:
      return None
    elif value.isdigit():
      return int(value)
    else:
      return -999999999

spark.udf.register('udfInt', udfInt)

df.selectExpr("*",
              "udfInt(Score) AS new_Score").show()

#+---+-----+----+----------+
#| ID|Score|hits| new_Score|
#+---+-----+----+----------+
#| 01|  100|null|       100|
#| 02| null|  80|      null|
#| 03|spark|   1|-999999999|
#| 04|  300|   1|       300|
#+---+-----+----+----------+
```

Filter on -999999999 to identify non integer (bad records)

```
df.selectExpr("*","udfInt(Score) AS new_Score").filter("new_score == -999999999").show()

#+---+-----+----+----------+
#| ID|Score|hits| new_Score|
#+---+-----+----+----------+
#| 03|spark|   1|-999999999|
#+---+-----+----+----------+
```

The same way you can have customized udf for float conversion.

Comment: Good thought process .,, Now i should find a way if i can use such UDF for 100 or more columns ...

Comment: Cool! If it solves your issue then don't hesitate to accept this answer and mark question as answered ;)